# Issue in passing parameter on stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure without any problem. I have tested before creating the procedure but when I try to execute my procedure I have a problem only in the first parameter I have

SQL SERVER 2008 SHOW ME Error syntax in 'Mundus'

```
ProcAvancementTotalbyEtab 'Erasmus Mundus','C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Table1.xlsx'
```

and After I try to make like this:

```
ProcAvancementTotalbyEtab N'Erasmus Mundus','C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Table1.xlsx'
```

This is my stored procedure:

```
alter proc ProcAvancementbyEtab
(

@nameEtabb  nvarchar(50),
@FilePath nvarchar(60)
)

as
begin
 EXEC
 (
 '
 SET NOCOUNT OFF;
 insert into Avancement(nameEtab)
SELECT distinct T.[EFP]
From OPENROWSET(''MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
''Excel 12.0;Database='+@FilePath+''',
''SELECT *
 FROM [Sheet1$]'') T

  where T.[EFP] is not null  and T.[Avancement] is not null
 and 
not exists (select * from Avancement where 
Avancement.nameEtab=T.[EFP])
and T.[EFP]='+@nameEtabb+'
 ')
end
```

When I comment this line 
    and T.[EFP]='+@nameEtabb+'
it works fine so my probleme is here

```
and T.[EFP]='+@nameEtabb+'
```

and when I test without stored procedure it work also OMG.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `name` is stored as a string.  You need an extra pair of quotes:

```
and T.[EFP] = '''+@nameEtabb+'''
```